# Помогите разобраться: "...краткие списки с судеб, признанных на тот момент героев"

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов

> С почтением перебирала фотографии табличек братских могил Гражданской,
>   осознавая, что, вероятно, в последний раз человеческий глаз касается
>   этих скромных строк – имя, две даты через тире. Многие могилы уже
>   тогда, в 70-х, терялись в бесконечных лугах и перелесках, а папки эти
>   будут лежать в самом низу, первыми в очередь на уничтожение. Страшно,
>   что в основном это списки фамилий совсем мальчишек. От шестнадцати до
>   девятнадцати. Теперь жалею, что не фотографировала эти **краткие
>   списки с судеб, признанных на тот момент героев**. В архиве запрещено.

Списки с судеб?

И - просто убрать запятую?

Answer (score 1):

Оборот "краткие списки с судеб" кажется мне необычным, но всё-таки допустимым.

В качестве иного варианта можно предложить автору "посмертные слепки судеб".
Но я не уверен, что эта альтернатива удачнее.

А запятую, как мне кажется, стоит убрать.

Comment: Я автору послала, нарисовав: ***...эти слабые отголоски судеб  признанных на тот момент героев***, но не уверена, что примет (вестимо). Автор ознакомляется с вопросами-ответами.